# CANopen protocol

Tags: can

If a [CANopen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CANopen) device is said to be CANopen compliant (for example, compliant to [DS 301](http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=440)), is the criteria for saying it to be compliant ***only*** based on the Mandatory Object Dictionary Entries supported or are there any other criteria we have to take care of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must support the mandatory object entries and also the functionality behind them.  There are many CiA specifications that cover different aspects of CANopen.  To say you meet the mandatory objects of 301 is fine - you comply to 301.  But what about 302 - Addtional application layer functions, 303 - Connector and pin assignment, 305 - LSS? The list goes on.

It really depends on what you are doing with CAN, who your target market is and what your customers require.  Dont forget the "Device Profiles", which may conflict with the standards also.

See here: http://www.can-cia.org/index.php?id=85

Comment: ya i agree this. For example if i support all the object entries as per 301, and the way in which i use the subindices is different, for example if SDO read request for reading main index 0xXXXX and subindex 0xYY has come & i will send all the mapped variables from subindex 0x00 to 0xYY. In this way am i violating the standard ? My device will be able to communicate with Standard third party CANOpen devices in the market?

Comment: Yes, from what you describe you will not be CANopen compliant - an SDO read request expects only that index/subindex combination to be returned

Answer (score 1):

All the criteria are in the specification from the physical to the object layers. Other layers in the [OSI model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model) are mandatory to be compliant.

Unless stated in the specification as "shall be", "may be", "user options", etc., it is mandatory. Active verbs or verbs, like "is", "must", or "will", are all mandatory.